# Nginx location redirect always to my app

Tags: nginx

I have a rails webserver with puma and nginx
This is the configuration

```
upstream puma_mydomain.it {
  server unix:/var/apps/mydomain.it/shared/tmp/sockets/mydomain.it-puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name mydomain.it www.mydomain.it;
  return 301 https://www.mydomain.it$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mydomain.it;
    return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.it/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.it/privkey.pem;
  server_name www.mydomain.it;
  root /var/apps/mydomain.it/current/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_mydomain.it;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
  error_page 503 @503;

  location @puma_mydomain.it {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    ssi on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_pass http://puma_mydomain.it;
    # limit_req zone=one;
    access_log /var/apps/mydomain.it/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /var/apps/mydomain.it/shared/log/nginx.error.log;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location = /50x.html {
    root html;
  }

  location /helloworld.html {
    ssi on;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_pass https://liveblog.mydomain.it/api/upload-raw/blogs/5c20ff839a954a50bec0a4b9/index.html;
  }

  location = /404.html {
    root html;
  }

  location @503 {
    error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
  }

  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
  }

  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    return 503;
  }
}
```

I've added the location "helloworld.html" as test: basically I need that everytime i call mydomain.it/helloworld.html nginx open the remote url page.

I cannot understand why https://mydomain.it/helloworld.html always return my rails app with an error on routing...

Comment: Maybe i forgot "=". ssl on is wrong or ssi ?

Comment: My bad. But test the server using `curl -I https://example.com/helloworld.html` to see if the proxy is being hit at all.

Comment: ```$ curl -I https://dday.it/helloworld.html
HTTP/2 301
server: nginx/1.13.10
date: Thu, 03 Jan 2019 10:58:35 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 186
location: https://www.dday.it/helloworld.html
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-frame-options: DENY
x-content-type-options: nosniff```